# Which process is eating my hard drives?

Tags: monitoring, freebsd, hard-drive

Today, after I logged in with ssh, I see a lot of lag on my FreeBSD server.

Something is eating 100% of my both hard drives (RAID1 with gmirror).

#### systat -vmstat

```
    5 users    Load  0,06  0,16  0,27                  17 май 14:22

Mem:KB    REAL            VIRTUAL                       VN PAGER   SWAP PAGER
        Tot   Share      Tot    Share    Free           in   out     in   out
Act  460540    7948   801208    12784  194524  count
All  629936    9364  2957060    16072          pages
Proc:                                                            Interrupts
  r   p   d   s   w   Csw  Trp  Sys  Int  Sof  Flt    291 cow   25887 total
  3         156       49k 7994 8300  17k 1420 5504   4011 zfod        irq0:
                                                       84 ozfod       stray irq0
 1,6%Sys   3,2%Intr  6,1%User  0,0%Nice 89,1%Idle       2%ozfod     1 ehci0 16
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |       daefr    12 atapci0+ 2
=+>>>                                                3845 prcfr     1 ehci1 23
                                       176 dtbuf     4040 totfr  2000 cpu0: time
Namei     Name-cache   Dir-cache    118650 desvn          react  5885 em0:rx 0 2
   Calls    hits   %    hits   %    102699 numvn          pdwak  4812 em0:tx 0 2
  194130  193731 100      56   0     29662 frevn          pdpgs       em0:link 2
                                                        4 intrn  4301 em1:rx 0 2
Disks   ad6   ad7                                  223380 wire   2875 em1:tx 0 2
KB/t   8,33  7,54                                  421760 act         em1:link 2
tps       6     6                                 2223088 inact  2000 cpu2: time
MB/s   0,05  0,04                                   81352 cache  2000 cpu1: time
%busy   100    95                                  114116 free   2000 cpu3: time
                                                   114880 buf
```

#### uname -r

```
8.2-STABLE
```

#### top

```
last pid: 17495;  load averages:  0.14,  0.25,  0.32     up 22+02:39:00  14:19:54
161 processes: 1 running, 151 sleeping, 9 zombie
CPU:  7.3% user,  0.0% nice,  2.0% system,  2.9% interrupt, 87.8% idle
Mem: 397M Active, 2171M Inact, 217M Wired, 79M Cache, 112M Buf, 127M Free
Swap: 8192M Total, 4540K Used, 8187M Free
```

#### gmirror status

```
      Name    Status  Components
mirror/gm0  COMPLETE  ad6s1d
                      ad7s1d
mirror/gm1  COMPLETE  ad6s1f
                      ad7s1f
```

It's not a swap, not a gmirror rebuild, no process is eating CPU.

So what is eating my drives? How can I detect the culprit?

Comment: NOM. It's me. <eats hard drive> NOM NOM NOM NOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this command:
top -mio -ototal

Comment: 4.55% mysqld, all other 0%. systat show bad values? But i see lags.

Comment: mysql -e 'stop slave' return systat to 2% busy. So it was mysqld.
Thanks.